# Avoid template when initializing `std::priority_queue` with home-made `std::Compare`?

Tags: c++, templates, compare, priority-queue

Is it possible to get rid of the template in the following code?

The idea is to use a `std::priority_queue` with classes honouring the `Compare` concept via an home-made abstract class.
Some of the problems I faced are:

- The priority queue wont init with an abstract Compare.
- there is no default constructors for classes inheriting from `Compare`, because they all have specific parameters.
- an `Algorithm` is responsible for initializing the data structure used by the `Compare` instances.
- **EDIT:** there may exists several implementations of `Algorithm`, using different data structures needing a `Compare`, and the user of the class should be able to decide which Compare he want to use.

I dislike the design given hereafter because people implementing `Algorithm` are not really forced to call `Compare::attach` and the `Compare` class should thus have a state management (not shown here).

It also force the user to indicate a compare template AND pass the corresponding instance (because the compiler cannot infer it in the constructor of an `Algorithm`). This is mitigated by the `make_algo` function, but I would rather avoid this exotic construction (not *that* exotic, but still).

**Is there a design in which I can use the `Compare` abstract class in an `Algorithm` instead of a template?**

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

class Compare
{
private:
    std::vector<int>* _costs;
protected:
    std::vector<int>& costs() {return *_costs;}
    int cost(const int i) const {return (*_costs)[i];}
public:
    Compare() : _costs(nullptr) {}
    void attach(std::vector<int> & costs_) {_costs = &costs_;}
    virtual bool operator()( const int a, const int b ) const = 0;
};

struct CompCosts : public Compare
{
    virtual bool operator()( const int a, const int b ) const
    {
        return this->cost(a) < this->cost(b);
    }
};

struct CompEps : public Compare
{
    const int eps;
    CompEps(const int e) : Compare(), eps(e) {}
    virtual bool operator()( const int a, const int b ) const
    {
        return this->cost(a)-eps < this->cost(b)+eps;
    }
};


template<typename C>
struct Algorithm
{
    C & comp;
    Algorithm(C& comp_) : comp(comp_) {}
    virtual void operator()() const = 0;
};

template<typename C>
struct Algo : public Algorithm<C>
{
    Algo(C & comp_) : Algorithm<C>(comp_) {}
    virtual void operator()() const
    {
        std::vector<int> costs;
        this->comp.attach(costs);
        std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, C > queue(this->comp);
    }
};

template<typename C>
Algo<C> make_algo(C& comp)
{
    return Algo<C>(comp);
}


int main()
{
    CompCosts compc;
    Algo<CompCosts> algo0(compc);
    auto algo1 = make_algo(compc);

    CompEps compe(1);
    Algo<CompEps> algo2(compe);
    auto algo3 = make_algo(compe);
}
```

**EDIT2: as the solution proposed by Barry may not be obvious to everybody, here is the corresponding code**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

struct Compare
{
    virtual bool operator()( const int a, const int b, const std::vector<int>& costs ) const =0;
};

struct CompCosts : public Compare
{
    virtual bool operator()( const int a, const int b, const std::vector<int>& costs ) const
    {
        return costs[a] < costs[b];
    }
};

struct CompEps : public Compare
{
    const int eps;
    CompEps(const int e) : Compare(), eps(e) {}
    virtual bool operator()( const int a, const int b, const std::vector<int>& costs ) const
    {
        return costs[a]-eps < costs[b]+eps;
    }
};


struct Algorithm
{
    std::function<bool(const int, const int, const std::vector<int>& costs )> comp;

    Algorithm(
            std::function<
                bool(const int, const int, const std::vector<int>& costs )
            > comp_
        ) : comp(comp_) {}
    virtual void operator()() const = 0;
};

struct Algo : public Algorithm
{
    Algo(std::function<bool(const int, const int, const std::vector<int>& costs )> comp_) : Algorithm(comp_) {}
    virtual void operator()() const
    {
        std::vector<int> costs{3,2,1};

        using namespace std::placeholders;
        std::function<bool(const int, const int)> f = std::bind(comp, _1, _2, std::cref(costs));

        std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::function<bool(const int, const int )> > queue(f);
    }
};


int main()
{
    CompCosts compc;
    Algo algo0(compc);
    algo0();

    CompEps compe(0);
    Algo algo2(compe);
    algo2();
}
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a solution for you. Polymorphism is largely a runtime concept while templates work at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `priority_queue` holds onto an object of type `Compare`, any attempt at polymorphism there would lead to slicing and fail. But polymorphism is just really overthinking the problem anyway (like I did in the previous revision).

Just use type erasure. All your comparators will have a `bool operator()(int, int)`, like:

```
struct CompCosts
{
    std::vector<int> const& costs;

    bool compare(int lhs, int rhs) const
    {
        return costs[lhs] < costs[rhs];
    }
};
```

So they can all be handled by [`std::function<bool(int, int)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
using Q = std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::function<bool(int, int)>>;
```

And then just create your `Q` with whichever comparator you want to use:

```
Q queue_by_cost(CompCosts{costs});
Q queue_by_eps(CompEps{costs});
```

Comment: I'm not sure to spot the fundamental difference with the question code. Given the abstract base class interface, Compare have the functor interface and can be handled as `std::function`. The key question is: given that `Algo` has a code using a priority queue, how to pass a Compare instance to it. I failed to see how to do that without templates in your answer.

Comment: @nojhan You wanted to know how to use an arbitrary comparison object without having to use templates to encode its type - `Q` doesn't encode the comparison object into the type, you can at runtime decide what to pass in.

Comment: +1, fair enough. Now have you an idea on how I can avoid the `C` template in the `Algo` class? I want to allow the user to instantiate any combination of Algo×Compare.

Comment: @nojham Don't use a template - take a `std::function<bool(int,int)>` instead.

Comment: I cannot, because `Algo` is initializing `costs` that need to be known by the compare function. `Compare` have an `attach` member function for this specific purpose, but I cannot change the prototype of the Compare concept.

Comment: @nojhan You don't *need* the Compare object. Look at how I implemented `CompCosts`.

Comment: I see. I was puzzled because `Algo` is really supposed to hold `costs` in the real code, not CompCosts. But thanks to your idea, I moved data structures as argument of the Compare functor and used `std::bind` to build a `std::function` compatible with the Compare concept for the priority_queue. And it works. Thanks again.